# 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred

Tags: c#

I'm dealing with this exception, I read through the internet solutions but nothing helped. My code so far.

```
ServiceReference.CompositeType egk = new ServiceReference.CompositeType();
                egk = client.getStatus();
                appendToList(egk);
```

This method adds the obj to the list. At this part i receive the exception.
The issue is at the parenthesis, the dynamic composite is causing the problems but I need it to change dynamic and I also know that the composite obj has the parameters.

```
public static void appendToList(dynamic composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj is null");
        }
        else
        {
            var response = myList.Find(r => r.mName == composite.mName);
            if (response == null)
            {
                myList.Add(composite);
            }
            else
            {
                int n = 0;
                foreach (CompositeType item in myList)
                {
                    if (item.mName == composite.mName)
                    {
                        n = myList.IndexOf(item);
                        myList[n] = composite;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My full exception:

> Status: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(eserv.CompositeType)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: There must be some additional details with the exception that might point you to what is causing it.

Comment: I updated my initial post.

Comment: What is the definition of `myList`?

Comment: `static List<CompositeType> myList = new List<CompositeType>();` keep in mind that `CompositeType` and `ServiceReference.CompositeType` have different namespaces but are the same.

Comment: As a check, try replacing `myList.Add(composite);` with `CompositeType tempComp = composite as CompositeType;` and `myList.Add(tempComp);`. Just as a check to see if the Namespacing is causing problems

Comment: The count of myList is now 1 but tempComp is null.

Comment: That means that CompositeType != ServiceReference.CompositeType. Write a little convert method that takes in your CompositeType and outputs the CompositeType that the list is expecting

Comment: Yep, i said it few comments above. Any help with that?

Comment: Post your custom definition of the CompositeType class, then someone could help you with a convert method for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75200/discussion-between-george-and-bernd-linde).

Answer (score 1):

Try casting when adding to list, like; (if the list type is your own custom type)

```
  myList.Add(Convert.ChangeType(composite,typeof(CompositeType)));
```

or

```
   myList.Add((CompositeType)composite);
```

Comment: `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: Is that CompositeType is your custom class or system ?

Comment: It's custom, i made it.

Comment: check the members of dynamic composite, is that same as what you have in CompositeType?